# What is the correct way to specify gems that I only want included in certain os environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems

Recently I started add this to my Gemfile.

```
  gem "autotest"
  gem "autotest-growl" # So you get friendly notices
  gem "autotest-fsevent" if `uname`.chomp == "Darwin" # Autotest OSX Specific gems.  So autotests runs better and uses less processor on a Mac
```

Unfortunately the Gemfile.lock file still ended up on the non mac CI and is now failing the build, meaning the if statement became pointless.

What is the correct way to specify gems that I only want included in certain os environments?

**Edit:** Platforms looks cool, unfortunately I want to make it so I can specify gems for OSX but not for our linux server. Further suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue on windows, for mswin32 specific gems

Answer (score 0):

See the [platforms section](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-) of the Gemfile documentation. Note that this does not give you all options, notably you cannot specify Gems specific to Mac.

Comment: Any suggestions then how I can differentiate OSX only gems?

Comment: It's not possible automatically, as far as I know. But you could make a group for them and have those not on OS X install without that group. It's not optimal at all, but it is a solution. Hopefully in the future the Bundler team will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
platforms :mswin do
  # windows specific gems
end

platforms :ruby do
  # non-windows gems
end
```

See [this section](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-) in the Gemfile manual for more information.